# Twilio Connect verb is not firing off Websocket connection in Twilio Function

Tags: twilio

I am using a Twilio function to serve a connect verb like so:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  const openFile = Runtime.getAssets()['/connectTwiml'].open;

  const twiml = openFile();
  console.log("Responding with Twiml:");
  console.log(twiml);
  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```

The asset value being pulled from the /connectTwiml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Connect>
    <Stream url="wss://<ngrok Url>>">
    </Stream>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

When I use  in this asset file it works upon receiving a call, so I am not questioning that the function is not firing and parsing the Twiml correctly, but when using  the websocket connection never fires to my ngrok endpoint.

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Were you able to fix that? I have the same problem.